# Tableau Parameters - Calendar Picker shows older months, how do we set it to default to current month?

Tags: parameters, datepicker, calendar, tableau-api

Tableau Calendar Picker shows older months, how do we set it to default to current month?
There are reports which were developed back in 2010 and shows that year and month in the calendar picker which makes it difficult to the user to type or navigate to the latest date. Please can you share any ideas to default this view to current month and the user can navigate to older months/year if required.

Example:

[Calendar picker showing 2015](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhsIc.png) Can this be set to default view of the current month Oct'2019, and the user can change the date if required

Answer (score 0):

You can use the quick date filter setting wherein it allows you to default to current date. Its present under the relative date option when you apply filter on the date field.

A video from official Tableau article can be seen [here](https://youtu.be/VFG0bmteAvM).